# Pass Object to $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

Ok I don't figure out how to solve this. I have following state:

```
    var myState:ng.ui.IState = <ng.ui.IState> {
        url: '/new/{order.orderNumber}',
        controller: 'OrderController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/order.tpl.html',
        resolve: {
            order: ['OrderService', '$stateParams', '$q', duplicateOrder]
        }
    };
```

I go to this state with:

```
this.state.go("myState", {"order": order});
```

This doesn't work, the method duplicateOrder inside the resolveFunction can't find the order Object, the $stateParams is completely empty.

If I use a String everything works fine. I use UI-Router v0.2.18 since I read it objects were possible since v.0.2.13

Answer (score 0):

You should add `params` on your `state` object like this:

```
var myState:ng.ui.IState = <ng.ui.IState> {
        url: '/new/{order.orderNumber}',
        controller: 'OrderController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/order.tpl.html',
        params:{order:null},
        resolve: {
            order: ['OrderService', '$stateParams', '$q', duplicateOrder]
        }
    };
```

What that piece of code do is it will initialize the `$stateParams.order` with `null` and whenever you send a parameter with `$state.go("myState",{order:order})` it will set the value with that data.